# Android EditText with active state

Tags: android

How can I have a surrounding line on the EditText border to indicate that this is currently on focus in Android ? What's the simplest way to achieve this globally (affecting all layouts) ?

**UPDATE**

My styles.xml

```
  <style name="EditTextCustomHolo" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_states</item>
    </style>
```

Edit_text_states.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_background" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_normal" />
</selector>
```

Edit_text_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Bottom indicator color for the UNSELECTED tab state -->
            <item android:top="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/text_color" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The above configuration is used for setting the white background to the `EditText`. How can I add lining border to the EditText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect in many ways, but most likely simplest would be to create drawable (XML) image with `<selector>` and reference different images depending on the state (you do not need to define all states). [Here's documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) (see "State List" chapter), or random [SO's question on similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542557/android-different-edittext-backgrounds-for-different-states-using-shapes-select) (search for more yourself).

Comment: I've found the above configuration in my android project. Could I keep the white background and still able to add the lining border ?

Answer (score 1):

Like Marcin says that's the way to do it.
Now for affecting all the layouts yo should override the attribute EdiText in your custom theme.

Something like this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:drawable">@drawable/custom_edit_text</item>
     ....
</style>
```