# Change drawable when a field gains focus

Tags: android

I have several`EditText`fields in my layout xml. All of them follow this pattern:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/EditText"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:hint="Email Address"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/icon1" />
```

If this field gains focus, I want to set the `drawableIcon` to `icon1` and if it loses focus, I want to set it to `icon2`.

I know I can do it using `setOnFocusChangeListener` in my activity.

But I want to ask **is it possible to do it using XML only**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be easily done using simple selectors once you create a custom drawable.

Check this tutorial where it applies what you want to a Button.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Something like this should work for you:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/EditText"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:hint="Email Address"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:background ="@drawable/customDrawableIcon" />
```

*res/drawable/customDrawableIcon.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon1"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon2"
          android:state_focused="false" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible, you need to create a selector xml for Edittext in your drawable folder, check this post he gave a good answer for this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543476/1007087

Answer (score 2):

You can use selector and change the state_focused drawable

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focusedIcon"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/normalicon"/>
    </selector>
```

so now the  android:drawableEnd should refer to the previous selector.

Hope this will help.