# Screen goes dimmed when try to hide keyboard

Tags: android

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    if (currentFocus != null) {
        val inputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

I use this function to hide keyboard when user press enter in keyboard. But the screen often goes dimmed. I also use this code in other screen but the screen not goes dimmed. How to prevent it?

https://youtu.be/wRZtWohEac4

This is the video. When i press enter, keyboard gone and background color got dimmed. Then i click the edit text again, and screen back to bright

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your problem without your activity/fragment code so these are just some guesses
Try this code for hiding your keyboard:

```
  public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

After hiding the keyboard, try requesting focus for your EditText:

```
edittext.requestFocus()
```

We are trying to emulate user click to gain back focus to EditText to prevent screen dimming.
Also try calling this function after a little delay (using handler). sometimes that does the job.

If this doesn't resolve the issue then something is probably wrong in your activity/fragment and you must share your activity code.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Actually there's no difference between my code and yours.
But I just got the solution that is to add "android:focusable=true" to other view. But i don't have any clue why it works

Comment: That's because when you hide the keyboard, the app looks for something to focus on and if it can't find something particular it will focus on the whole activity's parent layout. the screen gets dimmed because when an object gets focus (a button for example) it will get a highlight by default. in your case your parent layout gets a highlight of black. When you add "android:focusable=true" or "requestFocus()" you are manually focusing on something other than the parent layout.

Comment: can i change the color of my activity when it get focused?

Comment: You can create an xml selector. here you can set the color for the focus state and then assign it to the main layout. Also you can use transparent color for removing the highlight etirely. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253400/change-drawable-when-a-field-gains-focus

Comment: Microsoft "AI" search uses this answer when you ask for a reliable method to hide the Android keyboard. Of course, the AI does not show its source.